# Scheduling Recurring Jobs with Blocking Operations

Tags: scala, akka

I have a set of several Akka jobs that run at different schedules. Recently, I added a few jobs that are to run once a day that require reading a file from the disk and processing the data. Because reading from the disk is a blocking operation, my code waits and doesn't run any scheduled jobs when the schedule operation is performed. Does anyone know of a way for the scheduling thread to not be blocked by the pending disk IO operations? I've included the code of one of my actors below.

The scheduler code:

```
lazy val system = akka.actor.ActorSystem("system")
lazy val emailActor = system.actorOf(Props[EmailActor], name = "EmailActor")

system.scheduler.schedule(3 hours, 24 hours)(emailActor ! System.currentTimeMillis)
```

The actor implementation:

```
class EmailActor extends Actor {
  override def receive = {
    case _ => EmailSyncer.process()
  }
}
```

The processor:

```
def process() = {
  DataWarehouse.dataWarehouse withSession {
    val file = "/some/file/name"
    val emails = Try { Source.fromFile(file).getLines.map(l => Email(l)) }

    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Isolate reading operation into a separate actor?

Comment: I believe that's what I'm doing by scheduling the job. With the jobs that I currently have running, they run concurrently through the same scheduling mechanism.

Comment: Well, if you have several jobs that are reading from the disk concurrently, and the files you are reading are big, the only technique I can think of is to read the data in (relatively small) chunks and yield control after every chunk.

Comment: This isn't an issue of reading from the disk. The issue is when the jobs that require disk IO are scheduled (scheduled to run many hours away), the application stops running. It hangs waiting for an IO operation that isn't going to happen for a long time. In the meantime, there are other jobs that need to run in the next few minutes that don't run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a common problem in Akka. And so a pattern to solve it is readily available. Look into "Bulkheading". I've included a blog post below that shows you exactly what you need to do.

The general idea is that you can put different actors on different execution contexts or in slang "failure zones". This allows you to keep resource exhaustion and other problems from bleeding over into other parts of your app. Only the one execution context hits starvation, nothing else.

You can also tune the thread pools differently based on what each failure zone is doing. Generally, a large # of threads for blocking operations and for computation-intensive things it would be one thread per core to start and tune from there.

Good Luck.

http://letitcrash.com/post/40755146949/tuning-dispatchers-in-akka-applications

Comment: It turns out that blocking IO wasn't my issue. There was an exception that never had a stack trace printed. However, this answer was very helpful in helping me learn about handling resource exhaustion in Akka. Because of this, I will give you the accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks =) Keep it in your back pocket for once your app gets big. Can make a huge difference for performance and fault-tolerance.